# RSocket controller sending Reactor Flux message to IIS hosted signalR client but nothing is received

Tags: signalr, rsocket

In a dev environment a local IIS and signalR client web app creates a session with a spring boot RSocket server, and message flow is working fine.

After deployment to another server and a fresh IIS install, the signalR client can send messages to the server, creating a session from IIS port 6060 to server configured port, `X` (instead of 8082).

However, after the spring boot reactor `Flux` sends messages on port `X` back to the signalR client the messages are not being received by the client.

It's as if the IIS and signalR can fire and forget a send message to port `X` but not get a session that the port `X` can reply on.

Can anyone shed light on what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a fresh install of the `IIS <-> SignalR <-> RSockets <-> WebFlux` messaging stack on another demo server and the same error appeared to happen. Though did not run TCP packet captures to check the send / receive message situation with Wireshark.

First of all per [SignalR .Net Core 3.1 Web Application not working on local IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62089813/signalr-net-core-3-1-web-application-not-working-on-local-iis) the IIS WebSockets feature was not switched on.

Then, per [SignalR 2.2 returns 404 Not Found on IIS 8.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392489/signalr-2-2-returns-404-not-found-on-iis-8-5?noredirect=1&lq=1) the requests to the server returned 404 errors. A `/` was discovered in a JSON date String in `urlAPI` was causing call to

`using (_myStream = new StreamReader(await client.GetStreamAsync(urlAPI)))`

to find another endpoint in the `urlAPI` that did not exist, producing HTTP 404 errors. So that was due to malformed URL.